# ERROR : S_BROM_DOWNLOAD_DA_FAIL (0x7D4)

Tags: root, moto

Everything went wrong on flashing with SP Flash tool. The Preloader of Scattered file was checked and all others.
The problem is strange for me and I see that there are other with the same issue without an answer.
Fist of all I did everything described in forums. The driver of MT Preloader Vcom port is installed correctly. In Device Manager LTP com port is detected and as it is normal it disconnects in 2-5 seconds. If I change the USB port on PC it changes the COM port which is the previous detected.
The issue is that my latest SP Flash Tool 5.14 or even 3.13 older one, can't establish permanent connection with the COM port of the MTK 6589. I tested with different cables and different OS (XP and Windows 7 32 bit) on different computers with first pressing Download button of SP Flash Tool and then plugging the cable. If I don't press Volume Down button of my Huawei Ascend G610s it can't be dected of SP Flash. After pressing Volume Down the enters into Meta mode BUT .... SP Flash Tool report:
BROM ERROR : S_BROM_DOWNLOAD_DA_FAIL (2004)
[H/W] Fail to download DA to baseband chip's internal SRAM
[HINT]: 1. There's an cable communication problem between FlashTool and BootROM.
2. Target might be shutdown unexpectedly or target lost power supply.
[ACTION]
1. Try again.
2. Proceed H/W checking in download cable and target side com port.
3. Monitor if power-drop occured in target side.
At some reason COM port is constantly disconnecting and connecting without establishing permanent connection with SP Flash Tool. The red bar pops up and shows 100% done.

Answer (score 0):

**SP flash tool BROM Error** :- S_BROM_DOWNLOAD_DA_FAIL

Fail to download DA to baseband chip's internal SRAM!

**Reason**

1. There’s a cable communication problem between Flash Tool and Boot ROM.
2. Target might be shutdown unexpectedly or target lost power supply.
3. The DA is not correct.

**Solution**

1. Try again.
2. Proceed H/W checking in download cable and target side com port.
3. Monitor if power-drop occurred on the target side.

Find details and the Latest Tool - [sp flash tool](https://smartphoneflashtool.com)